# Pasting paths into gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, paste

How can I paste the path to a file or folder into the terminal. When I try to do this, it pastes the path as `file:///home/user/path/file`. How can I make it paste as a normal path. Guake terminal does this but sometimes I find it is better to use a normal terminal.

Comment: paste from where?

Comment: For clipboard solution on gnome-terminal see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/225666/copy-file-and-folder-path-from-nautilus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click and drag it into the terminal, you will see it as:

```
mehmet@mehmet-ThinkPad-W530:~$ '/home/mehmet/Desktop/tsm'
```